# Capture Image from Kinect v2 Sensor

Tags: graphics, windows-store-apps, kinect, win2d

I am new to Kinect development. I am using the Kinect v2 and to create a Windows store application following the Face Basics example found [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/12/31/kinect-for-windows-v2-sdk-playing-with-faces.aspx). I want to be able to capture a face image if the face is engaged. I am having trouble however capturing the image from the Win2D `CanvasControl`. I am not sure how else I can capture the face image.

Can anyone assist me with how I might accomplish this?

Comment: some specifics would by a good start point, what problems exactly? what language? where is your code that is problematic? which driver version you are using? which kinect model  ...

Answer (score 1):

In the Face Basics example, the author is storing the image captured by the Kinect sensor in a CanvasBitmap (eg line 38 of the ColorFrameSourceRenderer code snippet).

I assume that by "capturing the image" you mean "save to disk".  The contents of this bitmap can then be saved using the [SaveAsync](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_SaveAsync.htm) method.