# Capture a single image and save it Kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a small problem that I am sure has an easy fix but I am having difficulty finding an example or working code. I am programming in Visual Studio using C#.

I am trying to capture an image from the Kinect (v2) device. The device is already working as its intended in my programme and is displaying the colour feed and skeletal data on screen. When the user meets certain conditions, I want to write a method to capture 5 or so consecutive frames from the camera and save those image files somewhere on my computer.

I have been looking at examples such as [Capture Image from Kinect v2 Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803516/capture-image-from-kinect-v2-sensor)  but these aren't really leading anywhere! I have read that I should be using CanvasBitmap method but not really sure where to take it from there?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ColorBasics Sample, (stored in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v2.0_1409\Samples\Managed\ColorBasics-WPF` after you have installed the Kinect v2 SDK) shows you how to store the color stream into a `WriteableBitmap`.

You can then use the information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212771/save-writeablebitmap-to-file-using-wpf) to store the image.